# How to hide a actionbar for a moment on a layout which is not an activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, hide

I want to hide the action bar on my charging screen but it's not an activity, it's just a layout over an activity.

Comment: Explain clearly about what u have done till now and put some code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow: Please read the guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Otherwise it would be really hard for others to help you :-)

Comment: Define your question correctly post some code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call getSupportActionBar().show(); or getSupportActionBar().hide(); in your activity every time you want to show or hide your layout

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null){
        actionBar.show();
        //actionBar.hide();
    }
```

You can find more info about how to hide Android ActionBar [here](https://www.codevoila.com/post/76/5-ways-to-hide-android-actionbar)

Comment: Thanks man! it works nice! The problem was i hadn't initiated the ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); and i had to use the show() in other site of the code.